# US Equities: Gainers by Market Cap Dollars (not percent)

Tags: stocks, trading, yahoo-finance

There are quite a few web sites that offer daily gainers based on *percentage of price* for US stocks. For example: [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/gainers?e=us)

However, I do not want to use the metric of price percentage change; instead I want to use the metric of **market-cap dollar** change.

**Question:**
Where can I find daily **market-cap** gainers for US stocks in terms of largest dollar increase in market cap?

Comment: Not to be a wise guy, but when a stock rises X% in price, it rises X% in market cap as well.

Comment: Woops! Thanks Joe. I made a mistake.  I am looking for largest dollar changes in marketcap. I edited the question.